# Replacing a column in a table with values dependent on the current values in the column?

Tags: list-manipulation

I currently have  a table of absorbances vs. wavenumbers. How would I change that to a table of %transmittances vs. wavenumbers? The relationship is given by

```
%Transmittance = (10^(-absorbance))*100]
```

I've tried:

```
newtable = Replace[currenttable, i -> ((10^(-i))*100)]
```

No errors occur, but nothing happens.

Comment: You may use `newtable = currenttable;
newtable[[All, i]] = (10^(-newtable[[All, i]]))*100;` where `i` is the number of the column. If you wonder what `[[ ]]` is, look up `Part` in the documentation.

Comment: Is the table structured as a list of pairs in form {wave-number, absorbance}?

Comment: If you could show a brief excerpt of your table in your question, it would be easier to help you more effectively.

Answer (score 4):

Contrived data based on the element form {wave-number, absorbance}.

```
SeedRandom[42]; 
With[{n = 5}, data = Sort @ Transpose[{RandomInteger[100, n], RandomReal[1., n]}]]
```

> ```
> {{4, 0.142803}, {6, 0.628702}, {15, 0.290081}, {54, 0.0292846}, {66, 0.105067}}
> ```

Assuming you want to keep the original data and not destructively change the 2nd column in it, you could proceed as follows:

```
newdata = data;
newdata[[All, 2]] = 100 10^-data[[All, 2]];
newdata
```

> ```
> {{4, 71.9776}, {6, 23.5124}, {15, 51.2765}, {54, 93.4793}, {66, 78.5114}}
> ```

This works because all Mathematica's arithmetic operators have a property called `Listable`, which means they automatically map over lists such as `data[[All, 2]]`. In this case the operator doing the mapping is `Power`.